# Flash buttons take focus off of screen

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs4

In my flash movie, every time when I click on a button, it takes focus off of the stage. And I have to reclick the stage in order to interact with it again. Is there away to fix this issue. I am making a game and it will be very annoying if the player has to keep reclicking the stage in order to take control of the game every time they click on a button.

Comment: i don't believe thats possible because even youtube doesn't provide this. i guess you will need to make the buttons inside the flash as well.

Comment: Are you sure you have added keyboard event handlers to the `Stage` itself - if you used `this.addEventListener`, it adds to the root, not the stage. Stage will get all the events no matter what child has focus.

Comment: @antpaw I think OP is talking about Flash buttons.

Comment: @Amarghosh Are you saying that it depends on what object is listening for the button ?? Right now, the movieclip that the button is inside of is listening for the button to be clicked.

Comment: I was talking about the Stage, not the button. "I have to reclick the stage in order to interact with it again" - what kind of interaction - mouse or keyboard - how did you add those listeners?

Comment: well you mostly control the game with the keyboard. occasionally a box will pop up and you close it by pushing a button using your mouse. Then when I begin to control the character again, it wont allow me to. It is then I realize I have to reclick the screen again and by that time I have been shot up by an enemy. In my game I only have one Parent display object. everything goes into it. the listener is being placed on the button itself.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the listeners of the control buttons to the stage..

stage.addEventListener(Keyboard.... you know the rest.

if you add it this way, it will be invoked every keyboard event that you added,

UNLESS you the box that is popping is not a part of your flash game - then you have a problem which in the best case be able to fix with Javascript.

And if you're talking about free-hosting popup windows.. then you better find a better hosting place :)